# JDK 1.6.0.26 + Tomcat 7.x creates a problem for remote debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, breakpoints

Not sure.

I am using JDK1.6.0.26 plus Tomcat 7.x. When I am trying to debug a servlet that is deployed in Tomcat 7.x, it seems the connection to debugger was established in Eclipse, but the breakpoint was never hit even

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for breakpoint not hit is mismatch between the source and executed code. Try a method breakpoint on a common method, e.g. `service` or `doGet`